# Extend ClaimsAbpSession

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I need to extend the `ClaimsAbpSession` and create new properties to be sent in the requests between the angular app and the server.

Actually, I´ve stored these new properties using claims. But when the user refreshes the page, the values in the claims are lost.

Answer (score 3):

**MyAppSession.cs**

```cs
// Define your own session and add your custom field to it.
// Then, you can inject MyAppSession and use its new property in your project.
public class MyAppSession : ClaimsAbpSession, ITransientDependency
{
    public MyAppSession(
        IPrincipalAccessor principalAccessor,
        IMultiTenancyConfig multiTenancy,
        ITenantResolver tenantResolver,
        IAmbientScopeProvider<SessionOverride> sessionOverrideScopeProvider) : 
        base(principalAccessor, multiTenancy, tenantResolver, sessionOverrideScopeProvider)
    {   
    }

    public string UserEmail
    {
        get
        {
            var userEmailClaim = PrincipalAccessor.Principal?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "Application_UserEmail");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmailClaim?.Value))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return userEmailClaim.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs**

```cs
// Override CreateAsync method to add your custom claim
public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(User user)
{
    var claim = await base.CreateAsync(user);
    claim.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("Application_UserEmail", user.EmailAddress));
    return claim;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alper. That wayt the values added to the Session will be updated to token?

Comment: custom fields doesn't effect token.