# Get session in ASP boilerplate service layer

Tags: asp.net, session, aspnetboilerplate

I am currently use [AspNetBoilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) to implement my services in service layer...

So I can access session in MVC controller like:

```
 Token token = HttpContext.Session["Token"] as Token;
```

After login `Token` session be initiated....

I can access thta everywhere in MVC controllers but in ApplicationServiceBase it is null like:

```
public class AuditAppService : ApplicationServiceBase, IAuditAppService
{
    public GetUserActions_Box GetUserActions()
    {
        var token = HttpContext.Current.Session.GetToken();
        return GetUserActions_Box.Empty;
    }
}
```

`HttpContext.Current.Session` is null why?

that app services are implemented in separate library which is added in main web application.

I followed the documentation and crossed [This](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/v1.0.0.0/Abp-Session), I think `AbpSession` is not my solution which mean by it we can access some basics info about session that initiated by AbpBoilerPlate authentication system not ours.

Comment: You cannot reach asp.net session within an application service because application services are not part of the web layer.

Answer (score 1):

use `IAbpSession` .

you can use claims to add your custom values to the AbpSession.

previously answered here about how to extend AbpSession
[Extend ClaimsAbpSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802153/extend-claimsabpsession/45816317#45816317)

read AbpSession https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Abp-Session

Comment: Thank you man, I already read that two mentioned links before but I think `AbpSession` just hold some very primitive properties and it can't be customized as I need, or I am wrong.